# Render ember.js .hbs template to a string

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I currently can do the following:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile("Hello <em>{{name}}</em>!");
var html = template({ name: 'World' });
```

The `html` variable now holds the string `"Hello <em>World</em>!"`.

But how can I do the same with a template whose code is in a `.hbs` file inside my `app/templates` directory?

(I'm using ember-cli with ember 1.9.1)

Comment: What’s your use case?

Comment: I'm trying to use bootstrap popovers, and the `content` attribute, which holds the html to show in the popover, is given to it as a string. I would rather have it as a template, and generate the string on the fly, than hardcoding the html into a string in my javascript code, which looks ugly and it's harder to maintain.

Comment: although it's probably not very helpful in your case, I would discourage you from using bootstrap's javascript in the ember project to be honest... it's quite easy to wrap it up with ember and for sure it's gonna be more readable than trying to patch bootstrap's js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ember *1.13.15* this will work (**UPDATE** to work with v2.4 at the bottom):

```
// template-to-string.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default function(container, template, context) {
  let resolvedTemplate =
    typeof template === 'string' ? container.lookup('template:' + template) : template;
  context = context || {};

  Ember.assert(`Template '${template}' could not be resolved`, !!template);

  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve) => {

    Ember.Component.create(Ember.merge({
      style: 'display:none;',
      layout: resolvedTemplate,
      container,

      didRender() {
        resolve(this.$().html());
        this.destroy();
      }
    }, context)).append();

  });
}
```

It's based on a solution proposed in this post: [How to Render an HTMLBars Template to a String in Ember 2.0?](https://60devs.com/hacky-way-to-render-ember-template-to-string-in-ember-2-0.html) where further explanation is offered.

I have extended to support passing in a template context.

Use the function like so:

```
// my-component.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import templateToString from './template-to-string';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  _appendMyChildTemplate() {
    let myTemplateContext = ...;

    templateToString(this.container, '<my-template-path>', myTemplateContext)
     .then((html) => {
       this.$().append(html);
     });
  }

})
```

#### Update to work in Ember 2.4:

I can't claim to fully understand this or that it is anywhere near the best solution, but it works :)

Not massively different from the function above:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default function(container, template, context) {
  let resolvedTemplate =
    typeof template === 'string' ? container.lookup('template:' + template) : template;
  context = context || {};

  Ember.assert(`Template '${template}' could not be resolved`, !!template);

  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve) => {

    Ember.Component.extend(Ember.merge({
      style: 'display:none;',
      layout: resolvedTemplate,
      container,

      init() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        Ember.setOwner(this, container);
      },

      didRender() {
        resolve(this.$().html());
        this.destroy();
      }
    }, context))
      .create()
      .append();

  });
}
```